# 論理削除（ソフトデリート）したユーザをログイン不可にしたい

Tags: php, laravel-5

いつもお世話になります。

標記の件ですが、下記サイトを参考にコーディングしてみました。

Laravelの認証機能でユーザ情報の論理削除（ソフトデリート）を実装する

・・・が、ソフトデリートしたユーザのメールアドレス、パスワードを
ログイン画面で入力するとログインできてしまいます。

そもそも論でお聞きしたいのですが、ソフトデリートしたユーザであっても
ログイン可能なのは仕様なのでしょうか？

ちなみに環境は以下の通りです。

> Laravel 5.5 
>   PHP 7.2.7
>   MySQL 5.7.22

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

※以下、コーディングした内容です。
マイグレーションファイルの作成、マイグレートの実行

```
$ php artisan make:migration add_column_softDeletes_users_table --table=users
```

> $ view 2018_07_12_045301_add_column_soft_deletes_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddColumnSoftDeletesUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('deleted_at');
        });
    }
}
```

モデルの作成

```
$ php artisan make:model Models/Users
```

> $ view Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Users extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

下記SQL文にて、ユーザをソフトデリートしました。

```
update users set deleted_at = '2018-07-12 01:03:26' where id = 1;
```

前項でソフトデリートしたユーザでログインを試みるとログインできてしまいます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/135732

Answer (score 1):

そもそも論でいえば、Laravel (Eloquent ORM) の `SoftDeletes` トレイトは、自身が適用された `users` テーブルが、ユーザ認証に使われているかどうかについて関知しないので、`SoftDeletes` トレイトを用いて論理削除を設定したテーブルで、認証処理を実現するのは（つまりソフトデリートされたユーザを実際にログイン不可能にするのは）実装者の責任になります。

a. とは言え、例えば

```
$user = App\Models\Users::where(['name' => 'admin', 'password' => 'P@ssw0rd'])->first();
```

の様に、`SoftDeletes` トレイトを適用した `Users` モデルを経由してログイン処理を実装していれば、そのような仕様は自然に実現できると思うので、そのように実装したつもりなら実際の認証処理周りのコードを確認しないと何とも言えません。

b. しかし、もし

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where(['name' => 'admin', 'password' => 'P@ssw0rd'])->first();
```

の用なコードでログイン処理を実装していた場合、こちらは `SoftDeletes` トレイトを適用した `Users` モデルを経由しないので、`deleted_at` カラムの値に関わらず、論理削除されたレコードも返却されます（本題の仕様的に言えばログイン可能になってしまいます）。

c. もちろん PDO やその他の MySQL ドライバを用いて SQL を発行した場合も同様に（`SoftDeletes` トレイトが提供する）`deleted_at` カラムを用いた論理削除は考慮されません。

とにかく今一度ログイン認証処理まわりが `Users` モデルを利用して実装されていること、つまり「Eloquent ORM を通さずにユーザ認証にかかわるクエリを発行していないか」をご確認ください（実際の認証処理まわりのコードの添付も合わせてご検討ください）。